# SharePoint Content Query Web Part

Tags: list, sharepoint, moss

I have a content query web part that queries by content type against a site collection. I have grouped it by content type so I have:

```
-- Agenda (Content Type)
----Agenda #1
----Agenda #2
-- Report (Content Type)
----Report #1
----Report #2
```

I would like to show a second grouping for site, so:

```
-- Agenda (Content Type)
----This Site
------Agenda #1
----That Site
------Agenda #2
-- Report (Content Type)
----This Site
------Report #1
------Report #2
```

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this?

All the best
Kieran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have full access to change the xslt for the content query webpart. I reccomend exporting the webpart, saving the inline xslt into the style library and changing the webpart from using inline xslt to using a link to the file in the style library. This allows you to edit the xslt file using sharepoint designer which is much easier.